# Delphi - работа с БД

Tags: mysql, delphi, база-данных, api

Здравствуйте. Скажите, пожалуйста, как лучше подключаться и работать с БД (MySQL)? К примеру, если скорость интернет-соединения 1.7мбит/сек, то программа же постоянно подвисает на несколько секунд, пока не придут данные из БД. Логи и данные, которые надо только отправить, я делаю в отдельном потоке - с этим проблем нет.

Возможно ли оформить общение с БД не через компоненты, работающие с БД напрямую (к примеру zeos), а через web api? А если быть точнее, то будет ли данная конструкция работать быстрее? Если нет, то как можно еще организовать подключение и работу с БД?

Сайт и БД размещены на одном и том же сервере.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В дельфи всегда вроде была возможность создавать трёх-звенные приложения.

Web api может быть частным случаем этой архитектуры. И наверняка среди компонентов есть такие, которые работают через web.

Всякие там логи легко переносятся на сервер и по интернету не гоняются.

Что касается данных.
Никакое api никак не поможет ускорить интернет-соединение с БД. Какая разница каким api (sql, web, ещё что-то) закачивать результаты запросов с сервера? Они же ни при каком api меньше не становятся! А больше могут стать запросто.

Можно придумать постраничную загрузку данных тем или иным способом.

Уже не помню, но возможно сам дельфи загружает в буфера ровно столько записей, сколько помещается на экране в данный момент времени. По крайней мере когда БД поддерживает курсоры или при работе через свои трёх-звенные компоненты.
Надо просто закрывать все не нужные в данный момент наборы данных. Чтобы они не пытались обновляться ненароком и не грузились в фоне с сервера снова и снова.

Comment: Как тогда можно логировать действия? К примеру авторизация - сверка введенного логина/пароля с данными в БД. Разве есть какая-то процедура-функция (фича в конце концов), которая отслеживает тот или иной запрос и добавляет результат данного запроса в ту или иную таблицу?

Comment: Вы сами составляете программу и клиента и сервера и делаете там всё, что считаете нужным. У компонентов предусмотренно масса событий. В обработчиках нужных событий ведётся логирование. На счёт логина ничего определенного сказать не могу, но все действия с базой отслеживаются. Поищите материалы по трех-звенной, много-звенной (multi tier) технологии дельфи.

Answer (score 2):

Если ваша проблема состоит в том, что у вас замораживается гуй при выполнении запросов, то это решается асинхронным выполнением этих самых запросов. У компонентов, через которые происходит общение с БД, обычно есть специальные методы/режимы/способы для этого.

Например, у `ADO` в [TExecuteOptions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TExecuteOptions) можно указать `eoAsyncExecute` и по событию получить все данные. При этом, после начала запроса и до получения данных, основной поток не будет заблокирован и пользователю можно сделать какую-то индикацию, что идёт получение данных и даже дать возможность отменить запрос.

Статья о том, как это делается: [Асинхронная загрузка данных с помощью ADO в Delphi](http://www.proghouse.ru/programming/72-ado).

Comment: Моя проблема состоит в том, что у меня в программе практически при каждом действии идет общение с БД. При названной скорости интернет-соединения в вопросе каждый запрос, который не находится в отдельном потоке, выполняется по нескольку секунд. Такие запросы я не могу вынести в отдельный поток, т.к. на основе результатов запросов я уже вывожу ту или иную информацию и провожу манипуляции. Меня интересует как можно "ускорить" общение с БД.

Comment: Во-первых, вы сильно ошибаетесь, считая, что эти запросы нельзя выполнить в отдельном потоке. Выводить информацию и производить манипуляции с данными это ничуть не мешает.

Comment: Во-вторых, ускорить обмен данными с БД можно ускорив канал связи и/или уменьшив объём передаваемых данных. По поводу канала связи, ещё не факт, что вы в текущей своей реализации утилизируете его на 100%. Уменьшение же объёма передаваемых данных может быть связано с оптимизацией схемы БД и запросов к ней, использование сжатия данных и их кэширование на стороне клиента и т.д. Для тонкой оптимизации процесса обмена данными с БД, вам наверняка придётся писать свой сервер со своим протоколом обмена. Это очень сложное и широкое поле для действий, но нужно понимать, что делаешь.

Comment: Т.е. я полностью согласен, с товарищем выше - если хотите максимальной оптимизации, вам нужно строить трёх-звенную (мульти-звенную) архитектуру. Но надо понимать, что даже построив такую архитектуру, не факт, что у вас всё будет "летать". Таки законы реального мира ещё никто не отменял и передавать мгновенно бесконечные объёмы данных, пока что невозможно.

Comment: zed, насколько я понял, то надо на локалке с мускулом разместить программу, с которой будет взаимодействовать конечный пользователь. Получается, что прямого доступа к БД у юзера нет, а данные проходят через программу-посредника, верно? Если это так, то у меня возникает вопрос: почему так будет быстрее? И какой протокол связи между программами использовать? P.S. прошу прощения за все эти вопросы, но для меня сейчас данная тема темный лес =) впервые пытаюсь действительно что-то интересное и сложное реализовать.

Comment: Да, только не программу, а сервер приложений: http://mylektsii.ru/1-90057.html Быстрее может получиться из-за того, что между юзером и сервером будет передаваться меньше данных (в байтах) и канал связи будет использован по максимуму. К примеру из-за того, что при передаче по SQL протоколу может не использоваться сжатие данных (зависит от настроек и БД), включив, это самое сжатие, между юзером и своим сервером, вы на порядок повысите быстродействие.